# Regex to get all character to the right of first space?

Tags: regex

I am trying to craft a regular expression that will match all characters after (but not including) the first space in a string.

Input text:

```
foo bar bacon
```

Desired match:

```
bar bacon
```

The closest thing I've found so far is:

```
\s(.*)
```

However, this matches the first space in addition to "bar bacon", which is undesirable.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=\s).*
```

([**demo**](http://rubular.com/r/GaKBXEPMgG))

Although it looks like you've already put a capturing group around `.*` in your current regex, so you could just try grabbing that.

Comment: The OP wants the string following the first space, not the first whitespace; not, for example (in Ruby), `"ab\nc d"[/(?<=\s).*/] #=> "c d"`. You want `/(?<= ).*/`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer to use `[[:blank:]]` for it as it doesn't match newlines just in case we're targetting mutli's. And it's also compatible to those not supporting `\s`.

```
(?<=[[:blank:]]).*
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need look behind.

```
my $str = 'now is the time';
# Non-greedily match up to the first space, and then get everything after in a group.
$str =~ /^.*? +(.+)/; 
my $right_of_space = $1; # Keep what is in the group in parens
print "[$right_of_space]\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

```
(?s)(?<=\S*\s+).*
```

or

```
(?s)\S*\s+(.*)//group 1 has your match
```

With `(?s)` `.` would also match newlines

Comment: `(?<=\S*\s+)` is an invalid lookbehind.

Comment: I didn't try .net (I understand their regex flavor is somewhat non-standard). I know that in Java, Python and Ruby it doesn't work.

Comment: @arshajii .net supports quantifier in lookbehind